# How to handle breaks through CSS

Tags: css, line-breaks

I wanted only three items on one line after every three items the next three items should go on the next line. I wanted to do it without making changes to the HTML I tried this method in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bharath9207/vc2azrk6/) and wonder whether it is a right approach or is there any other way to handle it only through CSS

```
br{display: none;} br:nth-child(3n+0) {display: block;} p{display: inline}

<div>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a">abc</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b">bcd</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">cde</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="d" value="d">def</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="e" value="e">efg</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="f" value="f">fgh</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="g" value="g">ghi</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="h" value="h">hij</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="i" value="i">ijk</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="j" value="j">jkl</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="k" value="k">klm</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="l" value="l">lmn</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="m" value="m">mno</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="n" value="n">nop</p><br>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="o" value="o">opq</p><br>
</div>
```

Comment: You should ask it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have to keep the same HTML, without adding any classes then yes it is a good way to go. However if you can add a class to the parent div then you don't even need the br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floats without adding any break tags:

```
<div>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a">abc</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b">bcd</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">cde</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="d" value="d">def</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="e" value="e">efg</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="f" value="f">fgh</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="g" value="g">ghi</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="h" value="h">hij</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="i" value="i">ijk</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="j" value="j">jkl</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="k" value="k">klm</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="l" value="l">lmn</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="m" value="m">mno</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="n" value="n">nop</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="o" value="o">opq</p>
</div>
```

and for CSS:

```
div{width: 100%; float: left;}
p{width: 33.33%; float: left;}
```

This is just the way I would prefer instead of break tags.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc2azrk6/9/)

NOTE: You can adjust width of `p` tags as per your margin and padding just in case you have added them.

Comment: You have altered the HTML. As per the question, HTML cannot be changed.

Comment: Yes but I still prefer to get rid of those <br> tags and just in case I don't think this is being pre generated from backend or something so he might have the flexibility to change the html if that will yield clean code.

Comment: I agree. I have asked him about it. Lets see what he says :)

Comment: but you ended up giving a down vote :| anyways, if that seems right its okay :)

Comment: We wanted to achieve the output only through injecting CSS to the existing code in first place but it seems logical to remove <br> tag.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Without altering the HTML, i think what you have done is correct.

If you wish to alter by removing the br then

```
 <div>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a">abc</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b">bcd</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">cde</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="d" value="d">def</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="e" value="e">efg</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="f" value="f">fgh</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="g" value="g">ghi</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="h" value="h">hij</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="i" value="i">ijk</p>
    </div>
```

and css

```
div p {
  width: 30%;
}
p{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 33% width to the child elements. Here is a sample code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            br{display: none;} 
            br:nth-child(3n+0) {display: block;} 
            p{display: inline}
            div {
                width: 500px;
                float: left;
            }
            div p{
              width: 33%;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a">abc</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="b" value="b">bcd</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="c" value="c">cde</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="d" value="d">def</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="e" value="e">efg</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="f" value="f">fgh</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="g" value="g">ghi</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="h" value="h">hij</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="i" value="i">ijk</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="j" value="j">jkl</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="k" value="k">klm</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="l" value="l">lmn</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="m" value="m">mno</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="n" value="n">nop</p><br>
          <p><input type="checkbox" name="o" value="o">opq</p><br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```